# Is there any way to send ASP.NET Core 3.1 app telemetry to ApplicationInsights from Docker container on local host?

Tags: docker, azure-application-insights, metrics, telemetry

I am trying to find any solution or examples, how to send the telemetry of ASP.NET Core 3.1 application to ApplicationInsights from Docker container. I tried to send telemetry directly from Visual Studio on local machine and it works fine and it doesn't work from docker container. I tried to use different docker images from docker hub, which is old, and which should work with application insights, but it doesn't work as well. 
Is there any way to send telemetry from an application inside docker container to application insights at all? Could you provide some examples, please... Your help very appreciated!

Comment: Did you add the AI SDK to the projects?

Comment: yes, i did it in Visual Studio before wrapping project into the docker container